# Keras BERT - high accuracy, validation acc, f1, auc -> but predictions poor

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have trained a text classifier using google BERT via tf.keras.

My dataset consists of 50,000 rows of data, spread evenly over 5 labels. This is a subset of a much larger dataset, but I have chosen these specific labels as they are totally different from each other to try to avoid confusion during training.

I create the data splits as follows:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.30, shuffle=True, stratify=df['label'], random_state=10)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.1, shuffle=True, stratify=train['label'], random_state=10)
```

The model design is:

```
def compile():
    mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
    with mirrored_strategy.scope():
        learn_rate = 4e-5
        bert = 'bert-base-uncased'
        model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(bert, trainable=False)

        input_ids_layer = Input(shape=(512,), dtype=np.int32)
        input_mask_layer = Input(shape=(512,), dtype=np.int32)

        bert_layer = model([input_ids_layer, input_mask_layer])[0]

        X = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(bert_layer)

        output = Dense(5)(X)
        output = BatchNormalization(trainable=False)(output)
        output = Activation('softmax')(output)

        model_ = Model(inputs=[input_ids_layer, input_mask_layer], outputs=output)

        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(4e-5)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

        model_.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
        return model_
```

Which gives the following results:

```
loss: 1.2433
accuracy: 0.8024
val_loss: 1.2148
val_accuracy: 0.8300
f1_score: 0.8283
precision: 0.8300
recall: 0.8286
auc: 0.9676
```

When I run the test data through, and converting the one-hot encoded labels back to their original labels (having used `model.load_weights()`)...

```
test_sample = [test_dataset[0],test_dataset[1], test_dataset[2]]
predictions = tf.argmax(model.predict(test_sample[:2]), axis =1)
preds_inv = le.inverse_transform(predictions)
true_inv = le.inverse_transform(test_sample[2])
```

... the confusion matrix is all over the place:

```
confusion_matrix(true_inv, inv_preds)

array([[ 967,  202,    7,  685, 1139],
       [ 474,  785,   27,  717,  997],
       [ 768,  372,   46, 1024,  790],
       [ 463,  426,   27, 1272,  812],
       [ 387,  224,   11,  643, 1735]])
```

Interestingly, the third label is hardly being predicted at all.

Note that I set trainable=False in the batch normalization, but during training this is set to true.

The input data consists of two arrays: the numerical vector representation of the text strings (embeddings) and the padding tokens used to identify which of the 512 elements for each string are padded values.

What could be the causes of giving reasonable accuracy scores, but terrible predictions, on an evenly balanced dataset, trained with a deep pre-trained model (bert)?

Comment: Do you one-hot encode your labels for training the model?

Comment: Yep - Running the inverse_transform works correctly - converting them back into the original label (for both true labels and predicted)

Comment: Interesting problem. That's probably a long shot, but how do you create your test set? In case it is described by a different distribution than training and validation set, the model you learn might behave as you describe.

Comment: Thanks @GianlucaMicchi. I use sklearn's train_test_split. The test set represents 30% of the overall data, with stratification to ensure all labels are captured proportionally, and a random state applied too. (updated my question to add this in)

Comment: I have a hunch you don't save or load properly your trained model. Try to make predictions directly with the freshly trained model, without saving it to disk.

Comment: Thank you @igrinis - this is possible and I will try it. However how would I get around this problem when needing to use the model in a production setting in future?

Comment: There is no problem to use BERT in production, including loading fine tuned model. Just put attention to small details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case I resolved this by investigating the content of the 2 labels causing confusion. I did this using wordcloud. The example below shows my code for one of the labels:

```
from os import path
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline

df1 = df[df['label']==48000000]
text = " ".join(review for review in df1.text)
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, it was my understanding that BERT should be able to recognise which words are important to a particular label (using something like TF-IDF? not sure), however, when I remove stopwords using NLTK, and also by adding to that list the words which I think are generic to my specific dataset, in this case 'system', 'service' (etc), upon retraining a model the accuracies go up significantly:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def preprocess_text(sentence):

    # Convert to lowercase
    sentence = sentence.lower()

    new_stopwords = ['service','contract','solution','county','supplier',
             'district','council','borough','management',
             'provider','provision'
              'project','contractor']

    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    stop_words.update(new_stopwords)
    sentence = [w for w in sentence.split(" ") if not w in stop_words]
    sentence = ' '.join(w for w in sentence)
return sentence

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(preprocess_text)
```

[image]